# update the value of an object for a specific index during an state change in a reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, redux, reducers

I have an array of objects which has the following structure:

```
const obj = Object.assign({}, state.stuff.data);
```

where the value of `obj` is :

```
[
abc-123:{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""},
efg-345:{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""},
hij-678:{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""},
klm-919:{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""}
]
```

on a certain action/state change i need to update the values for `latency` for `obj[abc-123]`

I tried using the object,assign but this keeps on giving me the error:

```
    A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: 
`stuff.data.abc-123.latency`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action
```

What would be the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread syntax in object and add new property.

```js
const state = {
  'abc-123':{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""},
  'efg-345':{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""},
  'hij-678':{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""},
  'klm-919':{x: "1", y: "2", value: "", latency: ""}
}

const newState = {
  ...state,
  'abc-123': {
    ...state['abc-123'],
    latency: 1
  }
}

console.log(newState)
```

Answer (score 0):

react-addons-update helps with this sort of thing. it takes care of copying over the rest of the previous state and you can just update the data points you want with the dot operator.